# Visual Studio 2010 and/or win7 64 bit limits

Tags: visual-studio-2010, 64-bit

Does anyone have experience writing apps in VisualStudio 2010 C Premium that uses large amounts of ram and multiple cpus?

I am about to order a workstation with Dual hex-core Xeon 5690 processors (12 cores total, 24 hyperthreaded) and 48 gigabytes of RAM, but first would like to know if VS can handle that number of cores and RAM.

(Of course this is all 64bit)  I can't seem to find a straight answer either from MS or the hardware vendor, or from the Web.
Thanks

Update: someone just sent me [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778%28VS.85%29.aspx#physical_memory_limits_windows_7) link

I realize now that that my question was mis-directed.  The real issue is whether the target OS can address that much RAM and run dual cpu.

So, unless I'm misreading it, the infomation in the link above means that if you want to write an application that will run on Windows 7, and even if you require the 64bit version, you are limited to 16 gb.  The only way to get around that is require users to run Win 7 Professional, Enterprise or Ultimate 64 bit versions.

Comment: The real question is if *you* can handle it.  It is not easy to write a program that can consume that many resources.  I'll trade you that machine for mine, mine is much easier to program.

Comment: OK, I'll answer your "real" question as to whether I can handle it:  I run a complex series of analytical techniques over a 27gig data set, and must do so every minute.  The software never does the same calculation twice, but with new data arriving every minute, almost all of the calculations need to be updated.  (The calculations are variations of exponential moving avgs, so every minute the new data arriving requires the recalculation.) The app is running on a machine with 4 cores/8 threads, and it's too slow.  Now that I've answered your question, can you answer mine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little tricky to be sure quite what you mean. VS2010 can certainly produce output that takes full advantage of such hardware. And the IDE itself will run very nicely on such a roomy machine.

---

Your update discusses memory limits imposed by Windows itself. You say:

> If you want to write an app that will run on Windows 7, and even if you require the 64bit version, you are limited to 16 gb. The only way to get around that is require users to run Win 7 Professional, Enterprise or Ultimate 64 bit versions.

The reality is that nobody will buy a machine with more than 16GB RAM and then install an OS edition which does not support that amount of RAM. That would just be a waste of money. If your app requires more RAM than that and your customers are prepared to get hold of such a machine, then they will be quite happy to put the Pro version of Windows on it.

Comment: OK, I've addressed that update. But your question now appears to be more of a superuser question. Another point. I notice that you have not yet accepted an answer on Stack Overflow. Probably you haven't realised that it is polite to do so. See the [faq] and then look over your previous questions.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize that how it works (in terms of accepting an answer).  I will go back and rectify my other queries as well.  I just read the FAQ.  How do you indicate the question has been answered?  I just checked the green arrow and it still says 0...

Comment: The 0 is the number of votes. That's a parallel system. Anyone with 15 reputation can vote. Only the asker of question can accept.

Comment: OK, I finally got it.  I check the green arrow, but nothing registers.  Otheres who think it is a good answere somehow add votes

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio is *just an IDE*. Limitations are imposed by the compiler and an OS, and are usually listed in help under *Limitations* or something alike. Unfortunatelly, I don't have C compiler installed, but try searching through help while waiting for other answers.